# Button keeping focus

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I've got a `JDialog` that's created and set to visible whenever the button is clicked.
My problem is that the button keeps the focus and doesn't give it to the `JDialog`.

Is this a normal behaviour or there's something wrong going on ?

Comment: Got some sample code to demonstrate the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JDialog`s [aren't modal (are "modeless") by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28%29):

> Creates a *modeless* dialog without a title and without a specified Frame owner.

Try constructing it as:

```
new JDialog(owner, title, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

(Or the equivalent `super()` call if you're subclassing JDialog. Or whichever [modality type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dialog.requestFocus()` if `dialog` is the newly created `JDialog`.

See [`requestFocus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29) or [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) for more information.

Comment: If possible, could we link to the latest version of Java. At least it might highlight any deprecated methods that the OP might not be aware of ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thaks. fixed.